# Connecting LogParser to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, logparser

I've tried a wide range of connection strings trying to find one that will connect LogParser to my SQL Server 2017 (or SQL Azure) instance. I've tried both the ODBC and Native drivers. I've created and verified a DSN. Visual Studio will make the connection - LogParser's error message is misleading:

Error Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login
  failed for user ''

The user id property was supplied -- i've tried 'User ID=xxx'; UserID=xxx' and 'User_ID=xxx'. And when hitting SQL Azure (instead of on-prem) I've tried with and without the @[servername] suffix.

The DSN version:
-o:SQL -createTable:ON -oConnString:"Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};DSN=odbc_bw33;Connection Timeout=30;" -e:1

```
Task aborted.
Error connecting to ODBC Server
  SQL State:     08001
  Native Error:  0
  Error Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Neither DSN nor
  SERVER keyword supplied
```

Again, note that the connection string has a DSN name supplied - the error message is wrong.

I have been able to connect to SQLExpress with:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\seeder.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to help here, but please keep in mind that LogParser is doing next to nothing with the connection string you give it, it just passes it through to the ODBC API. I suggest you try to reproduce this with a simplified ODBC client, for example a few lines of Python code.

Comment: Appreciate the comment - any thoughts on why a DSN that correctly passes the 'Test Data Source...' button in the DSN config and that uses Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 14.00.1000 would fail with the same behavior?